# how to fetch the HTML source from ckeditor in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

how to fetch the **HTML** **source** from **ckeditor** in asp.net ? i want to fetch it into a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the [CKEditor control for ASP.NET](http://ckeditor.com/download):

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="chkContent" runat="server" Height="400" Width="800">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>

string content = chkContent.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following urls , hope it will help you.

http://www.itjungles.com/dropdownlist/how-to-use-fckeditor-in-asp-net-2-0

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/123324/Integrate-CKEditor-with-ASP-NET-page